# What is a clean way to handle one monad calling into another?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

Here is an issue of gluing together monads.  Not in a stack form, but in a form of needing to unwrap one monad to run the operation inside another.

Two domains: Weblog and App.  But, keep in mind that the App domain will be calling into additional ones in the same way that it currently calls in to Weblog.  Both have their own monad stacks.  Both keep track of their own state.

```
newtype WeblogM a = WeblogM (ReaderT Weblog (ErrorT WeblogError IO) a)
    deriving (Monad, MonadIO, Reader.MonadReader Weblog, Error.MonadError WeblogError)

newtype AppM a = AppM (ReaderT App (EitherT AppError IO) a)
    deriving ( Functor, Applicative, Monad
             , MonadReader App, MonadError AppError)
```

In order to run a `WeblogM` operation inside of an `AppM` function, I'm finding that I have to unwrap the `WeblogM` and rewrap it, using functions like this:

```
runWeblogHere :: forall a. Weblog.Weblog -> Weblog.WeblogM a -> AppM a
runWeblogHere weblog action =
    runIO (left . WeblogError) (Weblog.runWeblog weblog action)

runIO :: (e -> EitherT AppError IO a) -> IO (Either e a) -> AppM a
runIO handler = AppM . lift . handleT handler . EitherT
```

However, that does leave my actual passthrough operations quite simple:

```
getPage :: Weblog.PageId -> AppM Weblog.WikiPage
getPage pageid = do
    App{weblog} <- ask
    runWeblogHere weblog $ Weblog.getWikiPage pageid
```

This bothers me already because I have other monadic libraries that I already know that I'm going to plug in to the `AppM` architecture, and I'm worried about writing a `runXHere` method, which is really boilerplate, for each one of them.

I have a suggestion to create a `MonadWeblog` class to correspond to `WeblogM`, in much the same way that `MonadReader` corresponds to `ReaderT`.  That appeals to me more because I can start isolating the monad glue into my instance of `MonadWeblog` (or, really, `MonadX`).

Comment: Does that `MonadWeblog` help you though?  It seems like you want a generic version of `runXHere`; you might make a class which includes as methods whatever assumptions you need to implement `runXHere`.  It's not so unreasonable to have to implement this for each monad, though. Every monad usually comes with an eliminator into regular Haskell values, which you have to write. It is no crime for your eliminators to go into `AppM` instead.

Comment: Oh I think I see where you were going with the class.  Are all your monads going to be `ReaderT r (ErrorT e IO)`?  You might consider abstracting that as say `GenApp r e a`, basing all your monads on this, then writing combinators such as `embed :: (r' -> r) -> (e -> e') -> GenApp r e a -> GenApp r' e' a`, which makes `runXHere` trivial.

Comment: Yes to both questions.  I forget what exactly `WeblogM` is, but `runWeblog` returns `IO (Either WeblogError a)`.  The contract for each of my domains is that I can run it to get `IO (Either error a)`.  And that may be the key point for me to abstract things better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we ignore the newtypes, and convert both error transformers to `ExceptT`, the two monads stacks share a similar structure:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except (ExceptT, catchE)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader

type M env err r = ReaderT env (ExceptT err IO) r
```

Using the [`withReaderT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html#v:withReaderT) and [`mapReaderT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html#v:mapReaderT) functions, we we can define:

```
changeMonad :: (env' -> env) 
            -> (err -> ExceptT err' IO r) 
            -> M env err r 
            -> M env' err' r 
changeMonad envLens handler = withReaderT envLens . mapReaderT (flip catchE handler)
```

**Edit:** To ease the wrapping and unwrapping of the newtypes, we can make them instances of [`Wrapped`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.9.1/docs/Control-Lens-Wrapped.html#g:1) from the `lens` library, and define a more general conversion function:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

newtype N1 r = N1 { getN1 :: M (Int,Int) String r }

$(makeWrapped ''N1)

--instance Wrapped (N1 r) where
--  type Unwrapped (N1 r) = M (Int,Int) String r 
--  _Wrapped' = iso getN1 N1

newtype N2 r = N2 { getN2 :: M Int Char r }

$(makeWrapped ''N2)

changeMonad' :: (Wrapped (n1 r), 
                 Unwrapped (n1 r) ~ M env' err' r, 
                 Wrapped (n2 r), 
                 Unwrapped (n2 r) ~ M env err r) 
             => (env' -> env)
             -> (err -> ExceptT err' IO r) 
             -> n2 r 
             -> n1 r  
changeMonad' envLens handler = 
     view _Unwrapped' . changeMonad envLens handler . view _Wrapped'

changeN2N1 :: N2 r -> N1 r
changeN2N1 = changeMonad' fst (\c -> throwE [c])
```

`Wrapped` is a typeclass that says: "I'm actually a newtype, here's a generic way to add/remove the newtype constructor".

If the `lens` dependency is too heavy, the [`newtype`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/newtype) package provides similar functionality.